# Google Map and Place issue in Android X

Tags: android

I was using Google Map and Places API in my application:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
}
```

But after the update of Android X, I've got the following errors:

> Error: cannot access Hide
>           class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Hide not found
>
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

And also:

> Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'DaggerAppComponent